# Adding map current location(Latitude and Longitude) in ViewParams of Geoserver WMS using Leaflet

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, leaflet, wms

I am drawing Geoserver layers on google map using Leaflet. Base database for Geoserver is PostgreSQL.In PostgreSQL there is a table that stores Millions of polygon.These polygons are in the form of square of 300 sq. feet each. I want to search polygons within 50 Miles in circular radius from map's center location. For this I need center location of map whenever user zoom in/out or drag the map.So that I can do a query in PostgreSQL on the basis of location. Here is the code.

```
   //layersearcharea = user will enter this value.
  //layersearcharea is area that will be used in circular radius search 
  //algorithm or say KNN algorithm

    var viewparams = ['searcharea:' + layersearcharea,'centerlat:'+map.getCenter().lat,'centerlong:' + map.getCenter().lng];

                    var baseURL="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?";
                     var baseURL=encodeURI(baseURL+"viewparams="+viewparams.join(';'));

                var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms(baseURL, {
                    layers: 'MyWorkSpace:GetCellLayer',
                    transparent: true,
                    format:'image/png',
                    tiled:true
                }).addTo(map);
```

Question is How and where can I update centerlat and centerlong in viewparams whenever user change zoom level of map ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just listen to the event that is fired on `zoomend`, as described at http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#map-event

From what you've described, you probably also need to listen for the `moveend` event, because that would also change your centre point and hence the query you want to make.

Comment: In this event , do I need to rebind the WMS layer to map.

Comment: From what you've described, you're not changing the base map, but doing a separate postgis query.

Comment: map.on('moveend',function(){ //CODE THAT i HAVE CALLED ABOVE IN QUESTION })     Are you saying to do this?

Comment: Your implementation is up to you. The best way to do it depends on the rest of your code.